# A partial order on $\mathbb{N}$ that is not total

Tags: order-theory

In the text *Modern Real Analysis* by Ziemer there is a question that asks to use the "natural partial order" on $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})$ to obtain a partial order on $\mathbb{N}$.

I have scratched my head for some time but have failed to find a link between $\subset$ which is supposedly the natural partial order on $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})$ and a possible partial order on $\mathbb{N}$.

**EDIT:** I must mention that the question asks to find a partial order that is not total.

Comment: Can you give the full context?  There might be some prior explanation that makes this make more sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the full context (and a source of my confusion as well). It is an exercise tersely stated in exactly the same way I have mentioned. The only addition I can make here is the definition of partial and total order which are standard I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that, given $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, $a$ *precedes* $b$ if $b$ is divisible by $a$. This is a partial order, but not a total order because for example $6$ doesn't divide $7$ and vice versa.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the partial order $\subset$ on $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})$?

Comment: Yes, because you can identify a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ with the product of the elements inside it. For example $\{1,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}$ and $1\cdot3$ divides $1\cdot2\cdot3$.

Comment: This identification doesn't quite respect the partial orders in question, because $3$ and $1\cdot3$ divide each other but for set-inclusion we have only $\{3\}\subset\{1,3\}$ and not vice versa.